# Umbraco 7 : preventing editing of document

Tags: permissions, umbraco7, user-permissions

In case this is too long to read I have abbreviated this to this top section...

The Umbraco 7 back office editor checks whether the user can edit a document...can I hook into that and prevent edits based on user type and either a property on the document or at least document type?

I have tried the backoffice tweaking package but not sure if that will do what I need.

[Original post below]

> Still trying to prove Umbraco can host an Intranet for a client. And
>   to do that without having to code the underlying logic (ie happy to
>   create partial views with Razor and macros, but trying to avoid coding
>   at the Api level if possible - this frightens clients with issues of
>   supportability / upgradeability)
>
> I've kind asked this before, but may have to approach this from a new
>   angle.
>
> The idea is that the Intranet will have new articles : some that
>   anyone can create/edit and some that only admins can edit.
>
> I created two parent nodes ('user docs' and 'admin docs') and users'
>   starting node is 'user docs'.
>
> The home page combines lists of both, and anyone can view them so all
>   is well.
>
> However, the problem is they want to add comments to be listed under
>   each article.
>
> I created comments as child documents under the articles, and again,
>   this works really well, particularly using the markdown editor to
>   allow some styling of content.
>
> However, because ordinary users can't edit the admin articles, nor can
>   they create child documents.
>
> This is a shame as I was using the excellent Frontend Editing package
>   to allow them to edit documents from the front end.
>
> I was hoping to find a way to allow them to create child documents but
>   not edit / delete or unpublish the parent.
>
> I am coming to the conclusion there is no way of doing this with
>   Umbraco 'as is'.
>
> I did wonder about using some Ajax to create the comments documents
>   and linking them to the parent article but not sure where to begin?
>
> Any ideas?

Comment: Did you consider relating the articles with the comments with something other than a parent-child relationship? You can create a new Relation Type, for example "HasComment" in the Developer section.

Comment: I don't really understand relationships in Umbraco - I thought they were for linking two existing nodes. What I want is for users (not members) to select a document, and create a new (child?) document and for it to automatically relate to the original one when saving (without them having to use a picker or anything - it should be seamless and transparent). Can this be done?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what are you aiming at, but I think that some sort of extension or rather research towards ASP.NET Membership could help you. I am aware that Members section extends this .NET feature, but are the Users doing this as well? This article might answer most, if not all, of your questions: http://skrift.io/articles/archive/i-have-a-dream-about-user-management-in-umbraco/ Take a look at the section: *Related backoffice extensions*